# Odd behaviour of pwd with symlinks in terminal tabs

Tags: linux, bash, symlink, terminal-emulator, pwd

If I create a symlink through

```
ln -s /path/to/linked/dir current/path/link_name
```

and change the directory to `current/path/link_name` via

```
cd link_name
```

then I can check where I am using pwd-command. The output will be

```
current/path/link_name
```

But if I use some terminal emulator, such as terminator, konsole or others, I can split the tab or create a new tab in the same directory. The output of the pwd-command in the newly created tab will be

```
/path/to/linked/dir
```

In many cases, this is not convenient. Does anybody know how to change this behaviour in some terminal emulator(s)?

**P.S.** I also noticed that the output of `ls` typed from `/current/path/link_name` is the same as the output of `ls` typed from `/path/to/linked/dir`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The reason is that you lose the information on how did you get there after the system call has executed.  Some terminal emulators and mainly the `bash(1)` shell try to remember this, and implement `pwd` as an internal command, to cope with this scenarios.  But in general if you try

```
/bin/pwd
```

You'll discover that all the information about how did you get to that final directory was lost in the course of time.

Ask yourself how can the `/bin/pwd` work and how can it determine the directory you are on, and you'll answer yourself the question:

The system maintains a *current directory* (the `pwd` command inherits this from its parent shell) in the system data for each process, but to save resources, it only stores the inode number of the directory that is actually your current directory (not actually, it maintains a reference to the in-core inode structure).  It doesn't store the path you used to locate it, and it stores that info only to be able to get a starting point when you ask for a relative path when opening a file.  The problem is the same as determining which directory a multiple linked file belongs to... no parent directory is stored for a file, as it can be in multiple directories linking to it **all at the same time**... this is also true for directories, but they have an `..` entry inside themselves that links to their parents (their **true parents**, as one directory is now allowed to belong to different directories by means on normal links, this is forbidden by system, and ensured by the `mkdir(2)` system call)  The `pwd(1)` commands uses precisely these links to find the parent directory (and then find the current dir in the parent directory, by searching for the inode number of the current directory on it), until this algorithm leads to the same inode (the root directory has this special characteristic, its `..` entry points again to itself) so it stops going up.  `pwd` can only work because *it is following directories*, and never files.

Answer (score 0):

Terminator 1.90 does what you want. In an example session:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ mkdir a
$ ln -s a b
$ cd b
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> (or <kbd>o</kbd>, or <kbd>t</kbd>). At this point I'm still in `b`.

Comment: as mentioned by l0b0, splitting vertically and horizontally retains the working directory, but new tab is taking to the original directory in terminator

Comment: New tab does exactly the same as splitting here. That's why I mentioned "Ctrl-Shift-t".

Comment: Up to date Fedora 25.

Comment: I am running terminator 1.91 but why the behavior I observed is completely the opposite of what you mentioned. Is there any setting that could be causing this?